# Weird behaviour of system()

Tags: c++, qt, system

I'm a beginner in all this stuff. I'm trying to make a function that opens files (using Qt in windows), I tried some functions from   `QProcess` library but they are unable to fit in my needs.So, I decided to use system() function to execute files.The problem is system function only opening .exe files and other files from my system drive and is not opening any file from 
any other drive.Is there a built-in function in Qt that I can use to open any file with default program assigned for that file type. Why is this happening.What am I doing wrong?
My code:

```
    QString FilePath = openFileDialog.getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),"/home",tr("All Files"));
ui->Label_7->setText("Choose file to open.");
const char *file;
QByteArray bArray;
bArray = FilePath.toLatin1();
file = bArray.data();

system(file);
```

Comment: In Windows, there is start.exe, which does that for you. e.g. `start somefile.doc`

Comment: @urzeit Do you mean `QProcess::start()`, I tried it only opens .exe files.

Comment: Mckinzle: I meant `system("start somefile.doc")`, but the QT-Approach `hank` gave looks much better.

Comment: " opening .exe files " ... `"/home"`. I think I know why the OS tag is missing, you seem to be unsure yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `QDesktopServices::openUrl` function to open local files with a suitable application.
Try this:

```
void Widget::open()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
    if (!filename.isEmpty())
    {
        QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename);

        QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
    }
}
```